# {@ticket.image_file_name} not working in ActionMailer Attachment but fine everywhere else

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I'm able to use variables throughout my site except for in the attachment section of the ActionMailer. Do you have any recommendations on why I get the following error:

```
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - https://s3.amazonaws.com/logos/#{@ticket.image_file_name}
```

Here is the ActionMailer code:

```
def generate_tickets(ticket,business,contact,user)
  @business = business
  @ticket = ticket
  @contact = contact
  @user = user
  mail(from: "#{@ticket.user.first_name} #{@ticket.user.last_name} <reply@callred.com>", :to => "<#{@ticket.contact.email}>", subject: "Message is on its way")
  attachments['#{@ticket.image_file_name}'] = File.read('https://s3.amazonaws.com/logos/#{@ticket.image_file_name}')
  headers['X-MC-GoogleAnalytics'] = ENV["DOMAIN"]
  headers['X-MC-Tags'] = "New Ticket"
  headers['X-MC-Template'] = "maintheme|email_message"
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using string interpolation, you need to use double quotes instead of single quotes.

Change:

```
attachments['#{@ticket.image_file_name}'] = File.read('https://s3.amazonaws.com/logos/#{@ticket.image_file_name}')
```

To:

```
attachments["#{@ticket.image_file_name}"] = File.read("https://s3.amazonaws.com/logos/#{@ticket.image_file_name}")
```